# How can I print the address of first character?

Tags: c++

Why the entire string is displayed as outcome? Why address of 1st character not getting printed? How can I print address of 1st character?
Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char x[6]="hello";
    std::cout<<&x[0];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<<` operator on `std::cout` will treat a `char*` as a null-terminated string. You will need to cast it to a `void*` to print the pointer value.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char x[6] = "hello";
    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(x);
}
```

Comment: It's better to print the address as a `void*` instead of an `int`. `cout << (void*)x << endl;`

Comment: @RSahu Thanks - I have adjusted the answer

Comment: @Brett: How can I print address of suppose 3rd or 4th character using the technique you said?

Comment: @meet just change `x` to `&x[3]` like you originally had. I removed that because it's not necessary for the first character.

Comment: @RSahu: Why it is better to print address as a void*? What's wrong with int?

Comment: @meet, `int` might not be large enough to hold an address, which will result in truncation. Also, addresses are easier to read in hex than in decimal.

Comment: @Brett: Thank you sir for the valuable answer,

Comment: @RSahu not truncation, overflow :)

Comment: @Brett: Why you changed from reinterpret_cast to static_cast?

Comment: @meet good spotting :D I originally used `int` and a reinterpret_cast was necessary because a static_cast from a `char*` to `int` is illegal. However a static_cast from `char*` to `void*` isn't illegal, and therefore the reinterpret_cast is unnecessary, so I changed to static_cast. Both will work, however.

Comment: @Brett, casting a pointer to `int` can result in either truncation or integer overflow. The behavior is implementation defined. See section 4.7/3 of the standard.